# How to stop execution a Flux after a certain time in Java?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How can the publishing(Streaming) in Flux be stopped After timer **e.g. 1s**, if there are still numbers, they will not be published.
**e.g. after 1000** numbers, then they will not be printed.

```
@Test
public void test() {    
        
        Flux.range(0, 20000)
            // hier 
            .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1))
            .parallel(2)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .doOnNext(i -> {
                System.out.println(i);

            })
            .sequential()
            .blockLast();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Flux.take(Duration)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#take-java.time.Duration-) to cause the Flux to complete after a certain duration.

For the code you posted, and a threshold of 1 second, that would look like this:

```
Flux.range(0, 20000)
    // hier 
    .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1))
    .parallel(2)
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .doOnNext(i -> {
        System.out.println(i);
    })
    .sequential()
    .take(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) // <--
    .blockLast();
```